# CSS3 animations too fast and background image shaky a little bit

Tags: html, css, css-animations

After executing this, background changes too fast and also it is a bit shaking. Help me to slow down this background change and stop background to shake.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Banner -->
<section id="banner">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Enhancing Your <br />Ways</h2>
        <p>A free platform for schedualing</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS (Animation Delays not working)**

```
<!--The animation-delays not working--> 
@keyframes changebackground {
  0% {
    background-image: url("../Images/4.jpg");
    animation-delay:5s;
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url("../Images/1.jpg") ;
    animation-delay:5s;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("../Images/2.jpg") ;
    animation-delay:5s;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("../Images/3.jpg");
    animation-delay:5s;
  }
}

#banner {
  margin-top:2.9em;
  background-image: url("../Images/4.jpg");
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding:22em 0em 8em 0em;
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  animation-name:changebackground;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-duration:2s;   
  animation-delay:5s;
}
```

Comment: no question mark found!

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If yes, consider marking it as accepted (click on the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons near the answer). That is the way problems are marked as solved in Stack Overflow. If it didn't solve your problem [edit] in more information into the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to slow down the animation then the property that needs to be modified  is the animation's duration and not the animation delay. Set the `animation-duration` to a higher value. In the snippet, I have set it as `20s` and so the change from each image to the next will take around `5s`. If you need a time of `25s` between each switch, then set the duration as `100s`. `animation-delay` just adds a time delay before the start of the animation's first iteration but it doesn't really slow it down.

I don't really see a shake and so would need to see a demo of your code in-order to provide solutions. You may want to have a look at preloading all background images to stop it from causing problems.

```css
@keyframes changebackground {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4");
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2");
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3");
  }
}
#banner {
  margin-top: 2.9em;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 22em 0em 8em 0em;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  animation-name: changebackground;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s; /* set this */
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Enhancing Your <br />Ways</h2>
    <p>A free platform for schedualing</p>
  </div>
</section>
```